# NativeScript +Angular 2 + 3rd party Java Libraries

Tags: typescript, angular, nativescript

Today I started learning nativescript. I am trying to build simple ng2 app which would use 3rd party java library.  I am trying to achieve something like in here

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/using-native-libraries-in-nativescript/

but I keep getting undefined errors.

I have no problem of accessing java within my ts code:

```
import app = require("application");
import platform = require("platform");
declare var java;
.......
public get message(): string {
        var str = new java.lang.String('Hello world!');
        var result = str.endsWith('world!');
        console.log(result); // true
```

But I can't access 3rd party java library

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import app = require("application");
declare var KontaktSDK;

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    public counter: number = 16;

    public onTap(args) {
        KontaktSDK.initialize("API_KEY");
        this.counter--;
    }
}
```

It throws reference error "KontaktSDK is not defined"

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When accessing android native methods in nativescript you need to use the full package name and class e.g `com.kontakt.sdk.android.common.KontaktSDK.initialize("API_KEY")` also a little trick i picked up while developing nativescript plugins is you can use `console.dump(com.kontakt.sdk.android.common.KontaktSDK)` on a class and it would display all methods contained in that class . When in doubt log it out

Comment: Beat me to it @Osei. Also make sure you have the dependency built into the actual application. If you have previously ran this app, you need to follow the steps here: https://bradmartin.net/2016/07/20/ahhh-this-nativescript-plugin-doesnt-work/ this will ensure that you dependency is actually being packaged into the .apk and then run it. Also do what Osei suggests.

Comment: Awesome! thanks. Now i need to figure out how to access all of libraries's classes and grand app permissions :)

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions :- permission granting made ez :)